# Why is my object type not getting updated?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a permission service using react typescript and I ran into the following problem. I have the class:

```
import {IPermission} from "../interfaces/IPermission";

class PermissionService {
    private permissions: IPermission[] = [];

    constructor(permissions: IPermission[]) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public getValue(key: string): IPermission['value'] {
        const perm = this.permissions.find(permission => permission.key === key);
        if (!perm) {
            throw new Error('Could not find the permission');
        }

        return perm.value;
    }

    public modifyPermission(key: string, defaultValue: any, value: any): void {
        const perms = [...this.permissions];

        for (let i = 0; i < perms.length; i++) {
            perms[i].defaultValue = defaultValue;
            perms[i].value = value
        }

        this.permissions = perms;
        console.log(perms);
    }

    public parseActivePermissions(permissions: IPermission[]): IPermission[] {
        this.permissions.forEach(permission => {
            permissions.forEach(activePermission => {
                if (permission.key === activePermission.key) {
                    permission.defaultValue = activePermission.defaultValue;
                    permission.value = activePermission.value;
                }
            })
        })

        return this.permissions;
    }

    public getAll(): IPermission[] {
        return this.permissions;
    }
}

export default PermissionService;
```

and an AdminPermissions data file

```
import PermissionService from "../services/permission.service";
import {IPermission} from "../interfaces/IPermission";
import Permissions from "./Permissions";

const service: PermissionService = new PermissionService(Permissions);
service.modifyPermission('canAccessAcp', true, true);

const AdminPermissions: IPermission[] = service.getAll();
export default AdminPermissions;
```

The problem is, the `service.modifyPermission()` does not update the defaultValue and value of the permission. It's still false when console logging. Why is that?

UPDATE #1

Changed the file a bit. Still doesn't work. Now I'm directly changing the values, but they still log as false.

```
class AdminPermissions {
    public getAll(): IPermission[] {
        const service: PermissionService = new PermissionService(Permissions);

        service.permissions.forEach(permission => {
            if (permission.key === 'canAccessAcp') {
                permission.defaultValue = true;
                permission.value = true;
            }
        })

        return service.permissions;
    }
}
```

Comment: a log perms in console.log.How much does it have?

Comment: it doesnt work, sorry

Comment: check out the updated version of the post , please

Comment: values in service.permissions ?

Comment: {key: 'canAccessAcp', defaultValue: false, value: false}

Comment: it does return true for both values when I dont include UserPermissions. so UserPermission overrides the service.permissions array. but how?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `forEach` you are not changing the actual value of each items, so you should do something like this:

```
class AdminPermissions {
  public getAll(): IPermission[] {
    const service: PermissionService = new PermissionService(Permissions);
    return service.permissions.map(permission => {
      if (permission.key === 'canAccessAcp') {
        return (
          {
            ...permission,
            defaultValue: true,
            value: true
          }
        )
      }
      return permission
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

In the `permission.service.ts`

```
    public modifyPermission(key: string, defaultValue: any, value: any): void {
        const perms: IPermission[] = this.permissions.map(permission => {
            if (permission.key === key) {
                console.log('found permission');
                return {
                    ...permission,
                    defaultValue,
                    value
                }
            }

            return permission
        })

        this.permissions = perms;
    }
```